# Making broth more filling?

Tags: soup, broth

When I make a soup (planning on making a chicken soup tonight) I use chicken broth, creamer, and various seasonings. I love when I eat soup that has a filling broth because I always serve more broth than meat & veggies that are also in the soup. The broth doesn't need to be thicker but are there spices or veggies I could add that will make the broth itself more filling?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this can result in anything but random answers. If you want to consume more calories, any food you add will do. If you want to add things which you personally feel are filling, then it's subjective and depends on your own habits.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, my wife will sometimes add pureed carrots to achieve what (I think) you're going for. This principal of course isn't limited to carrots but you at least have the idea...
Again... FWIW

Answer (score 1):

Using a stock with more gelatin (from chicken bones and cartilage) will give it a heartier feel and taste.